# Countdown timer to specific date

Tags: c#, android, timer, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that displays total number of days, hours, minutes and seconds remaining to specific date.

That's what I've up to now created.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate (bundle);


  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

  txtDays = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDays);
  txtHours = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtHours);
  txtMins = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtMins);
  txtSec = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSec);

  DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 25, 12 ,30 ,00);

  DateTime todaysDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime formattedDate = todaysDateTime.AddHours (2);

  TimeSpan span = enteredDate.Subtract(formattedDate);

  double totalDays = span.TotalDays;
  double totalHours = span.TotalHours;
  double totalMins = span.TotalMinutes;
  double totalSec = span.TotalSeconds;

  new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                             {
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                  {
      Console.WriteLine ("Days: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalDays)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Hours: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalHours)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Minutes: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalMins)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Seconds: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalSec)));

      txtDays.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalDays));
      txtHours.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalHours));
      txtMins.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalMins));
      txtSec.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalSec));

  });
  })).Start();  

}
```

How to update TextViews every second automatically with Android C#?

**EDIT 2:**

I have used Timer, it's counting with Console.WriteLine, but the TextViews displays nothing and they don't updating... Somebody an idea how to update TextViews every second?

```
timer = 0;
      new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                                 {
      Thread.Sleep (1000);
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                      {
      tmr.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tmr_Elapsed);
      tmr.Start();
      while (timer < totalSec) ;
      tmr.Stop();

        });
      })).Start(); 

void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      txtDays = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDays);
      txtHours = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtHours);
      txtMins = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtMins);
      txtSec = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSec);

      DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 25, 12 ,30 ,00);

      DateTime todaysDateTime = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime formattedDate = todaysDateTime.AddHours (2);

      TimeSpan span = enteredDate.Subtract(formattedDate);

      totalDays = span.TotalDays;
      totalHours = span.TotalHours;
      totalMins = span.TotalMinutes;
      totalSec = span.TotalSeconds;

      Console.WriteLine ("Days: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalDays)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Hours: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalHours)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Minutes: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalMins)));
      Console.WriteLine ("Seconds: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalSec)));

      txtDays.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalDays));
      txtHours.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalHours));
      txtMins.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalMins));
      txtSec.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalSec));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved just added RunOnUiThread within tmr_Elapsed

```
void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
  txtDays = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDays);
  txtHours = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtHours);
  txtMins = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtMins);
  txtSec = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSec);

  DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 25, 12 ,30 ,00);

  DateTime todaysDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime formattedDate = todaysDateTime.AddHours (2);

  TimeSpan span = enteredDate.Subtract(formattedDate);

  totalDays = span.TotalDays;
  totalHours = span.TotalHours;
  totalMins = span.TotalMinutes;
  totalSec = span.TotalSeconds;

  Console.WriteLine ("Days: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalDays)));
  Console.WriteLine ("Hours: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalHours)));
  Console.WriteLine ("Minutes: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalMins)));
  Console.WriteLine ("Seconds: " + String.Format("{0:0}", Math.Truncate(totalSec)));


  txtHours.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalHours));
  txtHours.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalHours));
  txtMins.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalMins));
  txtSec.Text = String.Format ("{0:0}", Math.Truncate (totalSec));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# use `Timer` class and set that to 1 second.